# How to add length outside of square with tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

And this is what I got so far.

[image]

I am not sure how to add length x at the top.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,2){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,2){D}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,2){E}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=gray!10](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](D,B)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,A)
        \tkzLabelSegment[left=4pt](E,C){$7$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[below=4pt](B,A){$10$}
        \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,size=4pt](A,B B,C C,D A,D)
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(C,E,B)
        \foreach \Nodo in {B,D}
        \draw ([yshift=9pt]\Nodo) -- ([yshift=15pt]\Nodo);
        \draw[<->,>=latex] ([yshift=12pt]A) -- node[fill=white] {$x$} ([yshift=12pt]B);
     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical rules from B and D can be drawn using

```
    \foreach \Nodo in {B,D}
      \draw[help lines] ([yshift=9pt]\Nodo) -- ++(0,2.2cm);
```

The acotation rule (not sure of the name in English) can be drawn with

```
    \draw[<->,>=latex] 
      ([yshift=2.3cm]B) -- node[fill=white] {$x$} ([yshift=2.3cm]D);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,2){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,2){D}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,2){E}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=gray!10](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](D,B)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C,A)
        \tkzLabelSegment[below left=2pt](E,C){$7$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[below right=2pt](B,A){$10$}
        \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,size=4pt](A,B B,C C,D A,D)
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(C,E,B)
        \foreach \Nodo in {B,D}
          \draw[help lines] ([yshift=9pt]\Nodo) -- ++(0,2.2cm);
        \draw[<->,>=latex] 
          ([yshift=2.3cm]B) -- node[fill=white] {$x$} ([yshift=2.3cm]D);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does ` ++(0,2.2cm)` do? Is it a length of line?

Comment: @shin I already explained the meaning of `++` in a comment to an answer to other question of yours. `++(0,2.2cm)` adds `2.2cm` to the `y`-coordinate of the previous point. So, something like `\draw (A) -- ++(0,2.2cm);` draws a line from `(A)` to the point having the same `x`-coordinate as `(A)`, but with `y`-coordinate equal to `2.2cm` plus the `y`-coordinate of `(A)`.